Is there a way to enforce the number of members an enum is allowed to have?
Making an enum with exactly n many members is trivial if I've defined it myself:
class Compass(enum.Enum):
    NORTH = enum.auto()
    EAST = enum.auto()
    SOUTH = enum.auto()
    WEST = enum.auto()

## or ##

Coin = enum.Enum('Coin', 'HEADS TAILS')

But what if this enum will be released into the wild to be subclassed by other users? Let's assume that some of its extra behaviour depends on having the right number of members so we need to enforce that users define them correctly.
Here's my desired behaviour:
class Threenum(enum.Enum):
    """An enum with exactly 3 members, a 'Holy Enum of Antioch' if you will.

    First shalt thou inherit from it. Then shalt though define members three,
    no more, no less. Three shall be the number thou shalt define, and the
    number of the members shall be three. Four shalt thou not define, neither
    define thou two, excepting that thou then proceed to three. Five is right
    out. Once member three, being the third member, be defined, then employest
    thou thy Threenum of Antioch towards thy problem, which, being intractible
    in My sight, shall be solved.
    """
    ...

class Triumvirate(Threenum):  # success
    CEASAR = enum.auto()
    POMPEY = enum.auto()
    CRASSUS = enum.auto()

class TeenageMutantNinjaTurtles(Threenum):  # TypeError
    LEONARDO = 'blue'
    DONATELLO = 'purple'
    RAPHAEL = 'red'
    MICHELANGELO = 'orange'

Trinity = Threenum('Trinity', 'FATHER SON SPIRIT')  # success

Schwartz = Threenum('Schwartz', 'UPSIDE DOWNSIDE')  # TypeError

Overriding _generate_next_value_() allows the enforcement of a maximum number of members, but not a minimum.

An easier approach would be to check the number of Enum members of a subclass in an __init_subclass__ method:
class Threenum(enum.Enum):
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        if len(cls) != 3:
            raise TypeError('Subclass of Threenum must have exactly 3 members.')

Demo here
You can also create such a class with a factory function:
def exact_enum(number):
    class _ExactEnum(enum.Enum):
        def __init_subclass__(cls):
            if len(cls) != number:
                raise TypeError(
                    f'This Enum subclass must have exactly {number} members.')
    return _ExactEnum

Usage:
class TeenageMutantNinjaTurtles(exact_enum(3)):  # TypeError
    LEONARDO = 'blue'
    DONATELLO = 'purple'
    RAPHAEL = 'red'
    MICHELANGELO = 'orange'

Demo here

That environment you're using is faulty. If you run your code in an actual Python interpreter it will fail.

Thanks for the effort though. __init_subclass__ is a great suggestion and was one of the first things I tried. But it doesn't actually work. The reason is because it runs when the class is created which is before the members are instantiated, so all enums will have a length of 0 when it runs. You can see this by printing len(cls) before the length check. And as far as I can tell, there's no other way to see how many members are defined while inside __init_subclass__. You have to wait until the members are instantiated and then count them.

@ibonyun: The __init_subclass__ bug was fixed in Python 3.11.

@EthanFurman Aha, I'm using 3.9 at the moment.  Thanks for clarifying.

This is a job for metaclasses. The enum module provides a metaclass which you can extend with your desired behaviour. The simplest way is to define n in a metaclass.
class ThreenumMeta(enum.EnumMeta):
    """Meta class for making enums with exactly 3 members."""
    n = 3

    def __new__(meta, *args, **kwargs):
        cls = super().__new__(meta, *args, **kwargs)
        if len(cls) not in [0, meta.n]:
            raise TypeError(f'{cls} must have exactly {meta.n} members.')
        return cls

class Threenum(enum.Enum, metaclass=ThreenumMeta):
    """An enum with exactly 3 members."""
    ...

Doing this, you need a new metaclass for each value of n. If you need to do this with multiple values of n, or if n is unknown and needs to be dynamic, then you need something more flexible, a single metaclass that will allow you to specify the value of n.
class EnumMeta_NMany(enum.EnumMeta):
    """Meta class for making enums with exactly n many members, specified by kwarg."""

    def __new__(meta, *args, n=None, **kwargs):
        cls = super().__new__(meta, *args, **kwargs)
        cls.n = getattr(cls, 'n', None) or n
        if cls.n is None:
            raise TypeError(f'{cls} must specify required number of members with `n` kwarg.')
        if len(cls) not in [0, cls.n]:
            raise TypeError(f'{cls} must have exactly {cls.n} members.')
        return cls

class TwoEnum(enum.Enum, metaclass=EnumMeta_NMany, n=2):
    """An enum with exactly 2 members."""
    ...

class Threenum(enum.Enum, metaclass=EnumMeta_NMany, n=3):
    """An enum with exactly 3 members."""
    ...


Nice question/answer.

@EthanFurman Thanks. I think it's the first time I've ever had a question that didn't already have an answer on SO. And since the solution turned out to be considerably more difficult than I had imagined, and took me several hours to work out and fully understand, I thought it was worth sharing here.

@EthanFurman Holy smokes, you actually developed the enum module?! Very cool.  (￣^￣ )ゞ  So I presume you'd know if there were a better way. Since you haven't contributed an answer, can I assume that one doesn't exist?

The __init_subclass__ would be easier, but it's only usable on pythons 3.11+.  You're metaclass answer is the most widely usable.
